# Azure DevOps - New work item rule with action on "Iteration" field

Tags: azure-devops, workitem

I am trying to define new work item rule, and set action for field "Iteration", but it is not available.
What is the problem, and how I can solve it?

[image]

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/786946/allow-work-item-rules-to-set-iteration-path.html?childToView=1223751#comment-1223751 You can vote on this issue to make it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps - New work item rule with action on “Iteration” field

That because `Area Path` and `iteration path` fields are not included in the custom rule field list. And this issue has been reported as feature request to the azure devops team:

[Can't reference Iteration Path field when creating work item rules](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/338784/cant-reference-iteration-path-field-when-creating.html)

After a period of investigation, I may have found the reason for this situation.

To found the reason why only `Area Path` and `iteration path` fields are not included in the custom rule field list, I suppose is that its type may be different from other fields.

So, I imported one Process from TFS, then I found that the type of `Area Path` and `iteration path` fields are **TreePath**:

[image]

We could not simply determine if a value is a `TreePath` like the string type. Since we may include `\` in the `Area Path` and `iteration path` as string. For example, I create a new area name is `MyTest\Bug`, then my area path will change to: `MyTestProject\MyTest\Bug`. Now, problem is that `\` between  `MyTest` and `Bug` will treat as tree path instead of a string:

```
MyTestProject
     -----MyTest
            ----Bug
```

So, this may be the cause of this issue.

But I could not find any workaround for this issue, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you do not have any problem. This is feature of azure devops: Iteration Path always contains some value (minimum: Team Project Name as root of iterations). So your rule will not work.

You may post your needs as feature request  to the azure devops team: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea

That`s can be like: Add the Iteration Path field (and ignore root) or the Iteration ID field to the work items rules. Additionally describe your case and problem.

Comment: I choose "Make required" only for screenshot example. Same happens for any action I choose. So, I really don't understand, why I cannot choose "Set the value of" "Iteration" to the value I need.

Comment: I think, this is undocumented limitation of current design. There is Area ID for  Area Path, and Iteration Path may have the same behavior (Iteration ID). This is a question why there is no Iteration ID.